# Export Webi reports to Excel as an Excel tables

Tags: excel, business-objects, webi

I have a series of Business Objects (Webi 4.2) reports which are scheduled to be exported to Excel each day.

These reports form the basis of a Power BI dashboard.
Power BI is much happier looking at Excel Tables that it is simply worksheets so I would like to get Webi to export to excel but create the exported file as an Excel table.

This seems to be something that should be simple but countless hours of googling have not come up with an answer.

By default will be to use macros in Excel but it seems a bit messy for something that Webi could do?

Just want to have final check in the community before I go down the macro route.

Answer (score 0):

A macro is likely your best option; BO can only generate a simple Excel worksheet.